# Submit form details (to email) on successful payment

Tags: php, redirect, payment-gateway, payment

I have a payment integration working perfectly. Prior to that, my form submitted the form values to email. Now, all I want to do is allow a payment to be made to be made before that, and on after payment is successful, redirect to the "Success Url" and then submit the form values to email.
So how do I store the values and then enable them submit on the Success url page which ot redirects to after successful payment?
My code:

```
<form role="form" id="form-contact-agent" method="post" action="https://voguepay.com/pay/">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form-contact-agent-name"><?php echo JText::_('COM_BT_PROPERTY_YOUR_NAME');?><em>*</em></label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-name" name="name" value="<?php echo $this->user->name; ?>" required>
                                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form-contact-agent-email"><?php echo JText::_('COM_BT_PROPERTY_YOUR_EMAIL');?><em>*</em></label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-email" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->user->email; ?>" required>
                                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form-contact-agent-phone"><?php echo JText::_('COM_BT_PROPERTY_YOUR_PHONE');?><em>*</em></label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $this->user->phone; ?>" required>
                                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form-contact-agent-location"><em>Your Current Location*</em></label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-location" name="location" value="<?php echo $this->user->location; ?>" required>
                                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form-contact-agent-proposed-location"><em>Proposed Property Location*</em></label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control2" id="form-contact-agent-proposed-location" name="proposedlocation" value="<?php echo $this->user->proposedlocation; ?>" required>
                                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form-contact-agent-docs"><em>What documents are you applying for?*</em></label><br/>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="documents[0]" value="Architectural Drawing" />Architectural Drawing<br/>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="documents[1]" value="Structural Drawing" />Structural Drawing<br/>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="documents[2]" value="Mechanical Drawing" />Mechanical Drawing<br/>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="documents[3]" value="ElectricalDrawing" />Electrical Drawing<br/>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="documents[4]" value="Bill of quantities" />Bill of quantities (BOQ)<br/>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="documents[5]" value="Construction of building" />Construction of building<br/>
                                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                    <br/>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="terms" value="<?php echo $this->user->terms; ?>" required/>I agree to the Terms and Conditions 
                                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type='hidden' name='v_merchant_id' value='demo' />
<input type='hidden' name='merchant_ref' value='SC-CommitmentFee' />
<input type='hidden' name='memo' value='SC- Design Commitment Fee' />
<input type='hidden' name='store_id' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='success_url' value='http://www.myexample.com/thank_you.html' />
<input type='hidden' name='fail_url' value='http://www.example.com/failed.html' />

<input type='hidden' name='total' value='1500' />
</div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-default" id="form-contact-agent-submit">Apply Now</button>
                                    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                    <div id="form-contact-agent-status"></div>

                                    <input type="hidden" name="agent_id" value="<?php echo $this->agent->id ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="agent.sendmsg" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->uri->toString(array('path', 'query', 'fragment'))) ?>">
                                    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
                                    <?php include '/components/com_bt_property/controllers/agent.php';?>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Many ways, sessions, cookis, database, ... I'd say pick one?

Comment: @Naruto yes I know I can use sessions but can you give me a sample code of how I would pass a value to 'http://www.myexample.com/thank_you.html'? or 'http://www.myexample.com/thank_you.php'

Comment: Be careful with passing important data in hidden fields! If `total` is the total price and a smart user finds out it is used from the HTML form they might try to change the value and pay less.

Comment: @Naruto, sorry but how is this a duplicate? You can see clearly that my form action points to the payment gateway url and not just any random php page on my site. You can ask if you don't understand the question.

Comment: @Kwebble, thanks. But the payment is processed on the payment url, not on my site. So there is no way for it to be changed. The payment is not being processed on my site. Take a look at the "Form action"

Comment: I don't mean it can be changed on the server. What if the user posts this form with a different value for `total`? Will the payment provider perform a transaction for that changed amount?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think that will be an issue. But thank you for the observation

Comment: @Kwebble, any ideas on how I can use a session to store the values of the form and post to email after being redirected from successful payment?

Comment: It depends on how the payment provider works. But normally you have to create a payment transaction. Store the order and transaction ID in the database. Then it depends on the way the payment provider lets you know the result. It may be required to poll for the results or the payment server may report back by server-to-server communication. At that point you have the transaction ID and the result of the payment . Read the data back from the database using the transaction ID and do what's necessary, like send an email, or start process the order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124059/discussion-between-kesiena-sowho-and-kwebble).